# Regarding Image Format and GCP Processing in WebODM

Tags: image-processing, image-stitching, fieldimager

I am asking a question related to image processing, particularly in WebODM. Image stitching in WebODM, i have done it without GCP that works well. When working GCPs. It seems that for GCPs
import the imagery must be in .jpg/png format. I have collect the data through DJI Matrice 600 pro UAV. I have the imagery in .tif format. Could anyone kindly provide guidance on how to handle it? Is there a workaround to use GCP with the .tif format or should I consider an alternative method.